# What happens when spring bean definition file loaded into application multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am just curious to know when a `Spring.xml` file loaded into application multiple times into an application using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. For example if I want to get the services defined in `Spring.xml` into my claases by creating new instance of `ApplicationContext` in each class . Does this approach create each time new beans without destroying the previously created beans?Does this creates any memory problems ? When I see in [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) in spring website I found this.Does this refresh creates new bean definition of existing bean by destroying existed one?

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String... configLocations)
      ***Create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, loading the definitions from the given XML files and automatically refreshing the context.***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the same xml file is loaded several times spring creates the same beans several times. In most cases this does not cause problems except initiation time. But sometimes you can get conflicts. For example if you have bean that is listening to TCP port and then open yet another bean that tries to connect to the same port it fails.

Comment: So it means If I load that Spring Container 50 times into the application 50 instances of a bean will be created and lies in the session for the entire sessin time right? Does it causes memory issues in the application?

Comment: Not exactly. The new instance of bean will be created every time, so the old instance will be replaced by the new one. The old instance will be garbage collected then, so no significant memory issues are expected, although the performance of context initialization will not be optimal :)